# How to get defect image from unwrapped phase image?

Tags: phase

[image: x-direction phase]
[image: y-derection phase]
[image: defect image sigma = 1]
[image: defect image sigma = 5]

My problem is how to get the third and fourth image using first and second image.

The first one is unwrapped correspondence image in x direction.

The first one is unwrapped correspondence image in y direction.

The third one is defect image when sigma = 1.0;

The forth one is defect image when sigma = 5.0;

I read some documanetation it talked about **gaussian smooth**, **derivative sigma**, **convolusion**, **gradient** to calculate the defect image, I dont know how to combine them together.